# Build.Phonegap Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, sdk, phonegap-build

I am using the Build.Phonegap utility to zip up my HTML, CSS, & JS in order to create an app on my Android phone. I know my code is fully correct as it renders no problem in my browser, but when I zip it up the JS doesn't render at all. My question is:

**Can Build.Phonegap render third party Javascript SDKs? i.e. Facebook**

I am attempting to use the Facebook JS SDK and do not wish at all to use the Facebook.Connect plugin for Phonegap.
Please do not mix this up the Phonegap/Cordova platform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe it can, no. That's the point of the plugins.

Why don't you use the plugin?

Comment: Subjective Effect - because the plugin in supposed to be incredibly buggy as well as fragile compatibility issues. Too much for a newb!